# Run an .exe after installation using installshield

Tags: exe, installshield

In my MSI project, I require an `.exe` to be ran immediately after installing the product. The `.exe` comes with the product files. So I used a Custom Action to define this `.exe` to be run.

In the Custom Action Wizard:

```
TYPE = LAUNCE AN EXECUTABLE

LOCATION = INSTALLED WITH PRODUCT 

SOURCE = Service.exe

TARGET = [FOLDER_BEING_INSTALLED]Service.exe

RETURN PROCESSING = SYNCHRONOUS(CHECK EXIT CODE)

IN-SCRIPT EXECUTION = DEFERRED EXECUTION 

INSTALL EXECUTE SEQUENCE = AFTER INSTALLFILES
```

During installation using these settings the `.exe` does run, but it runs during the installation load screen and causes the installation to lock up and not finish.

Comment: Is that really a Windows Service? If so, you must register it as a real Windows Service and launch it using built-in mechanism in the MSI file to do so. This involves the ServiceInstall and ServiceControl tables. Please let us know what this file is, so we can follow up.

Comment: Instead I created a bat file to run the .exe. I implemented this into custom actions to a function in my installscript and it runs perfectly after the installation finalizes!

Comment: Is there a need to run this elevated? It might be enough to run the custom action asynchronously (no wait), or to use an immediate mode custom action after InstallFinalize if the exe requires no elevation to run (not that great, but better than a batch file). The latter may not work via SCCM, I am not sure - but corporate application packagers would disable such a custom action anyway. I am afraid batch files should generally be avoided at all costs. They might not work if you install to a custom installation path and several other problems (localization issues, policy restrictions, etc...).

Comment: Yes both the msi and the .exe should be run as admin. This is not a window service, just something for an emulator to run